# How to change the property values of class which is called under BaseTest - set up method

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

resources : c# , Nuniut , Selenium , VS 2017, restSharp

1) this is my test class, inherited BaseTest class.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ABCTest : BaseTest
{
     [Test]
    [Retry(Constant.IterationRunsInCaseFailure)]
    public void ABC_Output()
    {            
        Common.ExecuteTest(ABC.CheckAdd, GetType().Name, MethodName);
    }
}
```

2) This is base class, this will be executed first before any test.

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        Driver.ConfigInit();
        if (Driver.BaseAddress.Contains("dev.com"))
        {                           
        LoginPage.Login();
        }
        else
        {               
            Assert.Fail("Please check URL  ");
        }

// I am calling this "TokenGenerate" method to get token and other stuff.
//since it's defined under "set up" method I am not sure how to change the property values.

        string url = TokenRequest.TokenGenerate();
        Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

     }
}
```

3) this is "TokenRequest" class under a method "TokenGenerate" I am interested in.

```
public class TokenRequest
{
    public static string TokenGenerate()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("any url ");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        //  I want change the value of this PostMe properties for few test cases. since it's a executed under"BaseTest" and called before any test so I am not sure how to change these properties "Name, ProxyUrl etc" according to test. 

        var postMe = new PostMe()
        {
            Name = "ABC ABC",
            ManagementId = "ABC ABC",                
            ProxyUrl = ABC,
            SourceFilename = ABC,
        };
     }
}
```

4) this is actual implementation of test to run, which can be avoided here.
I have test cases like this and they all using default values of PostMe properties but I would like to change the values for this test case.

```
public class ABC
{       
    public static bool CheckAdd()
    {
        CommonOutput.OpenMediaAndClickCheckbox(Constant.ABC);           
        return true;            
    }
}
```

---

```
this is expected value for any test :
PostMe class is define with these properties separately in the project.

var postMe = new PostMe()
                {
                    Name = "ABC ABC",
                    ManagementId = "ABC ABC",                
                    ProxyUrl = ABC,
                    SourceFilename = ABC,
                };

but what I want for few test cases is :

var postMe = new PostMe()
                {
                    Name = "ABCDEF ABCDEF ABCDEF ABCDEF  ",
                    ManagementId = "ABCDEF ABCDEF ABCDEF  ",                
                    ProxyUrl = ABCDEF  ABCDEF ABCDEF ,
                    SourceFilename = ABCDEF  ABCDEF ABCDEF ,
                };
```

Please let me know solution or different type of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just changing the TokenRequst to this:

```
public class TokenRequest
    {
        public PostMe PostMe { get; set; }

        public TokenRequest()
        {
            PostMe = new PostMe()
            {
                Name = "ABC ABC",
                ManagementId = "ABC ABC",
                ProxyUrl = ABC,
                SourceFilename = ABC,
            }; ;
        }

        public TokenRequest(PostMe postMe)
        {
            PostMe = postMe;
        }

        public static string TokenGenerate()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("any url ");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            //  I want change the value of this PostMe properties for few test cases. since it's a executed under"BaseTest" and called before any test so I am not sure how to change these properties "Name, ProxyUrl etc" according to test. 

            var postMe = PostMe;
        }
    }
```